# Hyperbolic function problem, using identities to prove equivalent.

Tags: trigonometry

a.

Show that the equation:

$\sinh(2x) + 3\cosh(2x) = 10$

Is equivalent to :

$2e^{4x}  -  10e^{2x} + 1 = 0$

b. Hence solve the equation

Could anyone please point me in the right direction here? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how $\sinh$ and $ \cosh$ are related to the exponential function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definitions
$$\sinh(2x)=\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2} \quad \text{ and } \cosh(2x)=\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}\,.$$
To get rid of the negative powers of $e$, multiply both sides of your equation by $e^{2x}$.

To solve the equation $2e^{4x} - 10e^{2x} + 1 = 0$, note that it is a quadratic in $e^{2x}$.

Comment: Thanks, yeah ive used the identities, and ended up with...
.
.
.
 $e^{2x}$  - $e^{-2x}$ + $3e^{2x}$ + $3e^{-2x}$ / 2 = 10
.
.
= 
.
$4e^{2x}$ + $2e^{-2x}$  /  2 = 10

Comment: That's right. The left hand side simplifies to $2e^{2x}+e^{-2x}$. Now multiply both sides of the equation by $e^{2x}$.

Comment: ahhhhh thankyou!

Comment: Yes, you can use the quadratic formula:

Comment: $e^{2x}=\frac{10\pm\sqrt{10^2-4\times2\times1}}{4}$

Comment: Then take logs to find $x$

Comment: Was this factorized before using the formula?

Comment: I tried to use -10 for my b value

Comment: You can directly use the formula: $a=2,b=-10,c=1$

Comment: Thats the one... Thanks.